# Passing XML to Web Service via http POST

Tags: xml, http-headers, sas

I am trying to POST submit an XML string to the Manage Engine REST API (documentation [here](https://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/help/adminguide/index.html)).  I am doing this in SAS using the %http macro ([Garth Helf](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/100-30.pdf)).

My sent / received headers are as follows (XML non-urlencoded for brevity):

```
>>> HTTP Request:
POST /sdpapi/request?OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=666-666-666 HTTP/1.1
Host: DEV-SDPLUS
Content-Length: 101
Connection: Close

&INPUT_TYPE=<?xml version='1.0'?><Operation><Details> <subject>Test</subject></Details></Operation>

<<< HTTP Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FFE99B5C995093265402E5F54A09A056; Path=/
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; Tomcat-5.0.28/JBoss-3.2.6 (build: CVSTag=JBoss_3_2_6 date=200410140106)
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 135
Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2015 12:00:59 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Connection: close

<operation name="ADD_REQUEST"><result><status>Failed</status><message>No input data for creating request</message></result></operation>
```

The XML works fine (returning the workorderid)  when submitting via the url:

```
proc http out=out method="POST"     
   url="&MANAGE_ENGINE_URL/request?OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST%str(&)TECHNICIAN_KEY=&MANAGE_ENGINE_API_KEY%str(&)INPUT_DATA=%sysfunc(urlencode(&xml))" 
; run;
```

However this method breaks down with URLS of 512 characters and above.

**Does anyone have experience of using SAS to submit a long XML string to a web service?**

*EDIT: the proc http (512 chars) restriction appears to be SAS related, as I can successfully submit longer XML strings via the URL using CURL.  However we would like to avoid using command line (x curl) on the server if possible..*

Comment: Have you tried passing your parameters using the `in=` option? An example can be seen in the user guide [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0vfw4ml5fwn4un1ru90xy4s36oa.htm). This should avoid any character limits placed on the `url` option.

Comment: @SRSwift - so I just tried the in= approach (again) and it worked!!  I did try this several times originally but it didn't work, I think possibly due to the fact  was putting encoded (instead of raw) xml in the datalines, plus other reasons.  Feel free to put this down as an actual answer so I can accept..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `html` procedure can read the POST parameters from a `fileref`. An example can be found in the [user guide](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0vfw4ml5fwn4un1ru90xy4s36oa.htm). This will allow you to keep the `url` option to an acceptable length.

A rough example would be

```
/* Create fileref to store POST parameters */
filename in "/path/to/files/in.txt";
/* Create fileref to store http response */
filename out temp;

/* Write parameters to file */
data _null_;
   file in;
   input;
   put _infile_;
   datalines4;

&INPUT_DATA=<?xml version='1.0'?><Operation><Details> <subject>Test</subject></Details></Operation>
;;;;
run

/* Run the request */
proc http 
    in = in
    out = out 
    method = "POST"     
    url = "&MANAGE_ENGINE_URL/request?OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST%str(&)TECHNICIAN_KEY=&MANAGE_ENGINE_API_KEY"; 
run;
```

Comment: I updated with some minor changes as there was some invalid syntax - but still, just what was needed - thanks :-)